# How to use "Windows.Media.Miracast" API to develop UIBC function

Tags: uwp

I am developing a UWP app, the function is screen share sink and able to send UIBC to source side. Source side is Android app.

- The screen share function works well by using "Windows.Media.Miracast" API.
- But I don't know which API supports UIBC function.

I want to query which API is used for sending UIBC to source side?** such as: send mouse and keyboard event to source side.

Or no public API to support UIBC?

Comment: Now there are no tutorials and samples for Miracast in the official documentation. I also checked in [Windows.Media.Miracast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast?view=winrt-22621) namespace, and there is no API related to UIBC or similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Windows.Media.Miracast` namespace I found you can get input device through [MiracastReceiverConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast.miracastreceiverconnection?view=winrt-22621#properties), and [MiracastReceiverInputDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast.miracastreceiverinputdevices?view=winrt-22621) Class can return a [keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast.miracastreceiverinputdevices.keyboard?view=winrt-22621#windows-media-miracast-miracastreceiverinputdevices-keyboard),  you can try to implement the UIBC function through this.