# How to enable UIBC Mouse through UWP Miracast API?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, miracast

I am developing a Miracast sink app following the [UWP Miracast API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast?view=winrt-22621) and managed to get projection with User Input Back Channel (UIBC) for keyboard working. However, the API doesn't seem to implement mouse, only keyboard and game controller.

Another question asked here on SO made the keyboard support apparent ([How to use "Windows.Media.Miracast" API to develop UIBC function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74650051/how-to-use-windows-media-miracast-api-to-develop-uibc-function)), but mouse support is still unclear.

I'm wondering whether this is simply a limitation of the UWP API. Do you know if UIBC for mouse can be implemented in a different way? Maybe using .net or another Windows API.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [MiracastReceiverInputDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast.miracastreceiverinputdevices?view=winrt-22621), mouse is not supported yet.

I'd suggest you submit a feature request about this feature in the Feedback Hub.

Comment: Hi, let's continue this thread in [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1433455/how-to-enable-uibc-mouse-through-uwp-miracast-api?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1366886#newest-answer-comment)

Comment: Sorry, there is no public API to achieve such function.